# How to parse SOAP WSDL method XML response with Python?

Tags: python, parsing, soap, wsdl, response

I am consuming a SOAP WSDL to get list of countries using python suds library.
here is python code.

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
base_url = 'https://some_server/ws/CountryListService/CountryListService?wsdl'
client = Client(base_url, username='abc', password='abcd')
cuntrylist = client.service.getCountryList()
print(cuntrylist)
```

It prints as following.
How to read/get COUNTRYCODE and COUNTRYNAME in python from following response?
How to read/parse the following and to save it into a database table?

```
(COUNTRYLIST){
 COUNTRY[] = 
  (countryDto){
     COUNTRYCODE = "682"
     COUNTRYNAME = "Saudi Arabia"
  },
  (countryDto){
     COUNTRYCODE = "792"
     COUNTRYNAME = "Turkey"
  },
  (countryDto){
     COUNTRYCODE = "400"
     COUNTRYNAME = "Jordan"
  },
}
```

cuntrylist is following type of object

```
print(type(cuntrylist))
<class 'suds.sudsobject.COUNTRYLIST'>
```

I have many other SOAP WSDL methods and very complex responses and stuck how to get values?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it the following way.
First Convert Suds object into serializable format.

```
    def recursive_asdict(self, d):
    """Convert Suds object into serializable format."""
    out = {}
    for k, v in asdict(d).items():
        if hasattr(v, '__keylist__'):
            out[k] = self.recursive_asdict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            out[k] = []
            for item in v:
                if hasattr(item, '__keylist__'):
                    out[k].append(self.recursive_asdict(item))
                else:
                    out[k].append(item)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out
```

Calling SOAP service

```
client = Client(base_url, username='abc', password='abc')
cuntrylist = client.service.getCountryList()
country_dict = self.recursive_asdict(cuntrylist)
cls = country_dict['COUNTRY']

for item in cls:
   print(item['COUNTRYCODE'], item['COUNTRYNAME'])
```